# Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset

Tags: perforce, cruisecontrol.net

I have this block in the Cruisecontrol.net xml file:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
    <project name="MyProject">
        <artifactDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\Mydashboard</artifactDirectory>

            <sourcecontrol type="p4">
                <view>//Myprojectfolder/Code/...</view>
                <executable>c:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe</executable>
                <client>Myworkspace</client>
                <user>John</user>
                <applyLabel>false</applyLabel>

                <port>PERFORCEPR123:10080</port>
                <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
            </sourcecontrol>
            <tasks>

                <msbuild>
                    <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
                    <workingDirectory>D:\Workspace\Myworkspace\Code\src</workingDirectory>
                    <projectFile>Myproject.sln</projectFile>
                    <targets>Build</targets>
                    <timeout>1000000</timeout>
                    <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
                    <buildArgs>/v:minimal /noconlog /p:Configuration=Release</buildArgs>
                </msbuild>

            </tasks>

            <publishers>

                <xmllogger logDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\Mydashboard\Buildlogs" />
                    <buildpublisher>
                        <sourceDir>D:\Workspace\Myworkspace\Code\src\newsrc\Webapplication.site</sourceDir>
                        <publishDir>D:\deployment\Webapplication.site</publishDir>
                        <useLabelSubDirectory>false</useLabelSubDirectory>
                        <alwaysPublish>false</alwaysPublish>
                    </buildpublisher>
            </publishers>
        </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

But,when i build my project i am getting the below error:

```
BUILD EXCEPTION
Error Message:
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Perforce GetModifications failed: c:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe -s -c Myworkspace -p PERFORCEPR123:10080 -u John -P john123 changes -s submitted //Myprojectfolder/Code/......@2014/01/15:08:13:20,@2014/01/15:08:14:20
Error output from process was:
error: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
exit: 1

   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Perforce.P4.Execute(ProcessInfo process, String description)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Perforce.P4.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect CC is just using the Perforce command line client. To workaround this I would:

1) Add a group to Perforce and set the Timeout to unlimited.
2) Add the user running the CC task to the Perforce group
3) From the build machine run 'p4 -u  login'

This will store a local ticket that lasts forever to authenticate the user. If you need a an account to run tools like CC under, fill out this form and Perforce will give you a free background user:

http://www.perforce.com/support-services/request-background-user

Comment: Thanks Matt for the response.I had already added a group to perforce and set the timeout to unlimited and added the user i.e John running the cruisecontrol to that perforce group.Actually,initial i had this working but recently i have changed the server name and port number and now i am using the new server name and port number in the <port></port> tag.This issue started showing when i have changed the server name and port number.Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: You just need to login again. Part of the generated ticket name is the server it is attached to. Run 'p4 tickets' to see what a ticket looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bad ticket file, you will get this error.  Delete the ticket file, then run your tool or run p4 login to recreate the ticket.

*nix location: ~/.p4tickets

Windows location: C:\Documents and Settings\\p4tickets.txt

[Bug Reference](http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.perforce/2005-12/msg00125.html)

[p4 login reference](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_login.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me.

1. Set env variable P4PASSWD
   [image]
2. Open new cmd prompt,

> p4 login
> [image]